# ORACLE Database Resource Usage

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how check the database resource limit but I want to check the resource usage. How can I do that?

```
select * from user_resource_limits;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use V$RESOURCE_LIMIT that displays global resource usage at instance level.

See [Database Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-RESOURCE_LIMIT.html#GUID-AC182B2E-8D26-43D7-A356-BE1F15BDF152).